# PyCharm run django single test as part of class

Tags: django, pycharm

When running single test in PyCharm (django), the IDE create new config with target

```
boo.bar.tests.TestClass.test_whatwver
```

This will not run the test, as the class is considered to be a method

when running

```
boo.bar.tests:TestClass.test_whatwver
```

(with colon between `tests:TestClass` test will be executed

is there a way telling PyCharm doing it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that pycharm won't recognise custom `settings.py` (called 
 it `test_settings.py`), so it needs to be configured manually

go to **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Django** and set `Settings` file path to your local `settings.py`

Comment: I'm using a custom settings, and the path still contains a period instead of a colon. Did you do anything else to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening regardless to PyCharm, NoseTest is looking for : delimiter between filename and class

If you run with different test suit, it will run

In general, PyCharm is running a test helper for running tests

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py

If you override its default values (changing TEST_RUNNER value for instance), you might experience problems